# From the path of local device , get the image to set as wallpaper

Tags: android, storage, wallpaper

I have path of a wallpaper picked from the image gallery in string format. 
Now from that path , I want to get the image drawable or bitmap from the gallery or local storage and set it as wallpaper .

What i have done is :

```
if (!wallpaperPath.equals("") && wallpaperPath.length() > 0) {
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(wallpaperPath);
                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = (WallpaperManager.getInstance(ScrollingActivity.this));
                    try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(b);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But this gives me error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=WIFICHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in delusions.com.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$2@4e59142
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:874)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.WallpaperManager.setWallpaper(WallpaperManager.java:1524)
                                                                           at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:1278)
                                                                           at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:1207)
                                                                           at delusions.com.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$2.onReceive(ScrollingActivity.java:132)
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:864)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695) 
                }
```

What should be the correct way to do it ?

Code to get the wallpaper :

```
   case R.id.btn_wallpaper:
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            imageIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(imageIntent,"Select New Wallpaper");
            startActivityForResult(chooser,RESULT_WALLPAPER);
            break;
```

and in onActivityResult()

```
  if(data!=null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                System.out.println(" bundle string : "+ bundle.getString("data"));
                System.out.println(" check here :"+ data.getExtras()!=null?"OK":"NOTOK");
                System.out.println(" check here key 2:"+ data.getExtras().containsKey("dat")!=null?"OK":"NOTOK");
                Bitmap imagedata = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("dat");
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(imagedata!=null)
                    imagedata.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                tv_Ringtone.setText(encodedImage);
                Prefs.writeString(this,Defines.IMAGE_DATA,encodedImage);

                Uri wallpaperURI = data.getData();
                String wallpaperPath = wallpaperURI.getPath();
                System.out.println("Wallpaper path  encoded:  "+ wallpaperURI.getEncodedPath());
                System.out.println("Wallpaper path : " + wallpaperPath);
                Prefs.writeString(this, Defines.WALLPAPER_PATH, wallpaperPath);
                iv_newWallpaper.setImageURI(wallpaperURI);
            }
```

Comment: add full code for this activity/fragment

Comment: the path for the selected wallpaper is /document/image:9418

Comment: please add code for select image and set selected image in imageview which you had tried

Comment: why Base64.encodeToString ? what you exact want to do awith the selected image ???

Comment: I actually wanted to save it for later user

Comment: then u can store its URI no need to convert in Base64.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question from stackoverflow only but i missed the link  from where i did.

```
 if(data!=null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                final Uri wallpaperURI = data.getData();

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Bitmap imagedata = null;//(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("dat");
                            try {
                                imagedata = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), wallpaperURI);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            if(imagedata!=null)
                                imagedata.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                           String  encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                            Prefs.writeString(ScrollingActivity.this,Defines.IMAGE_DATA, encodedImage);
                            //tv_Ringtone.setText(encodedImage);

                        }
                    }).start();
                String wallpaperPath = wallpaperURI.getPath();
                System.out.println("Wallpaper path  encoded:  "+ wallpaperURI.getEncodedPath());
                System.out.println("Wallpaper path : " + wallpaperPath);
                Prefs.writeString(this, Defines.WALLPAPER_PATH, wallpaperPath);
                iv_newWallpaper.setImageURI(wallpaperURI);
```

And for setting that wallpaper is

```
 String previouslyEncodedImage = Prefs.readString(ScrollingActivity.this,Defines.IMAGE_DATA);

                if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
                    byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = (WallpaperManager.getInstance(ScrollingActivity.this));
                    try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```